# NHibernate.Spatial release for NHibernate 3.2

Tags: nhibernate

Just wondering if we have NHibernate.Spatial release for NHibernate latest version 3.2?

What I found only is NHibernate.Spatial version 1.0.0.0 for NHibernate version 2.1.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there are some breaking changes with version using spatial with NH 3.2 but there  is an interesting set of blog posts below which show you how to get it built with NH 3.1 - which may be good enough for you - worked for me.

http://build-failed.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/nhibernate-spatial-part-1.html

http://build-failed.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/nhibernate-spatial-part-2.html

http://build-failed.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/nhibernate-spatial-part-3.html

http://build-failed.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/nhibernate-spatial-part-4-querying.html

Comment: Lol, this was unexpected, that's my blog. Anyway, glad it helped you Patrick :P

Comment: @chobo2: I'll probably pick it up again this week

Comment: @psousa - Ok cool. I probably will have some questions for you after I go through your tutorials. What I am after is this. I have a longitude and latitude(say where I am standing) and I want to find all other longitudes and latitudes in my database  that are say in 20KM from where I am standing.

Comment: @chobo2: Those tutorials are slightly dated, just use the github version. Regarding your problem, I'll just have to make sure that the "Distance" operator is working with Geometry arguments.

Comment: Ok. I will use the github one. Can you let me know when you test the Distance operator?

Comment: I'll probably test it tonight, and I'll also add a unit-test for it

Comment: Is there a nuget version of it? Also is there something in github I can use to figure out how to use your library?

Comment: Hmm, I'm guessing the unit-tests should help... But I should add a sample project to the solution. Anyway, regarding the distance operator, the QueryOver is working correctly, but not the LINQ one. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Cool. Let me know how that goes. I will start including it into my project but still not sure if the nuget version is yours.

Comment: @psousa - Where in the unit tests is the queryover one? I tired to use the ones from you example tutorials but can't get it to work "Cannot find either column "NHSP" or the user-defined function or aggregate "NHSP.Distance", or the name is ambiguous."

Comment: @psousa - I created a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286892/nhibernate-spatial-dont-get-results-back. I still am getting the NHSP problem but I was able to use what was in the tutorial a bit but it returns no results.

Comment: @chobo2 - That's weird... Can you send me the project so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: @psousa - Unfortunately I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but NHibernate.Spatial is now available on NuGet and built against the latest NHibernate version (3.3.3) from a fork made by [Surya Pratap](https://github.com/suryapratap/Nhibernate.Spatial). See full announcement on my blog here: http://blog.printf.no/?p=1055